# having trouble chaining multiple axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Ok, so what I am trying to do is do an axios.get() request pull specific data an id specifically, then use that id that I got to put it as a string literal so I can do my second request. I keep getting Info is not defined.

```
axios
  .get(
    `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/bloodstrive?api_key=${api}`
  )
  .then(response => {
    info = response.data.id;
  })
  .then(
    axios.get(
      `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/${info}?api_key=${api}`
    )
  )
  .then(response => {
    summoner = response.data;
    return summoner;
  });
let getSummonerId = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(summoner);
};
module.exports = {
  getSummonerId
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your chaining:

```
axios
  .get(
    `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/bloodstrive?api_key=${api}`
  )
  .then(response => {
    return response.data.id;
  })
  .then(info => {
    return axios.get(
      `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/${info}?api_key=${api}`
    )
  })
  .then(response => {
    summoner = response.data;
    return summoner;
  });
```

Personally, I recommend async for tasks such as this. Makes handling things a lot easier with promises:

```
let fetchSummoner = async() => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/bloodstrive?api_key=${api}`);

    const info = res.data.id;

    const res2 = await axios.get(`https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/${info}?api_key=${api}`);

    const summoner = res2.data;

    return summoner;
}
```

Comment: o wow it was just returning info then sending the info on the second .then. THANKS ALOT

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez Async/Await chaining is awesome. Consider checking it out/using it: https://blog.logrocket.com/promise-chaining-is-dead-long-live-async-await-445897870abc

Answer (score 0):

In the current code you haven't added a return statement in the 2nd axios request. Failing to this will not fetch and return the 2nd url. 
Please try the below code.

```
axios
  .get(
    `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/bloodstrive?api_key=${api}`
  )
  .then(response => {
    return response.data.id;
  })
  .then(info => {
    return axios.get(
      `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/${info}?api_key=${api}`
    )
  })
  .then(response => {
    summoner = response.data;
    return summoner;
  });
```